# Instrumenting protractor from gulp in a multi-targeted build environment

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, gulp

I work on a project using angularjs with karma & protractor for testing and gulp as the taskrunner.The project aims to build multiple (slightly different) variants of the same app, for different clients with custom branding and selected functionality/features.
Mostly the apps share same code. 80-90% are identical.

I’m currently looking into how to instrument the end to end tests (using protractor) and found that the only way would be to create one config file per run configuration:

- VariantA.develop.spec.js
- VariantA.deploy.spec.js
- VariantB.develop.spec.js
- VariantB.deploy.spec.js
- … lather, rinse, repeat ...

My approach would now be to refactor the common parts out into shared modules, that each of these configs then `require`s and extends/changes as necessary.

However, I’m wondering whether there are alternatives to this approach?